# Quand utiliser « depuis » ou « de » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions

J'ai trouvé cette phrase dans une émission de **News in Slow French**.

> nous parlerons de la nouvelle mesure de l’UE pour combattre le passage de clandestins **depuis** l’Afrique.

Si j'avais écrit cette phrase, ce serait plutôt :

> nous parlerons de la nouvelle mesure de l’UE pour combattre le passage de clandestins **de** l’Afrique.

Est-ce correct aussi ? Sinon, pourquoi ? Comment savoir quand je dois utiliser « depuis » au lieu de « de » ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La présence de *depuis* est dûe à l'emploi de **passage** (On peut passer *depuis* un endroit A *vers* un endroit B). Hors de ce contexte, sans un autre verbe d'action similaire, on dirait plutôt *les clandestins d'Afrique* dans la plupart des cas. Ceci pour les mêmes raisons qu'on ne pourrait pas dire par exemple « Je suis *depuis* l'Afrique. »

L'expression *les clandestins de l'Afrique*, plus lourde, pourrait éventuellement convenir pour insister sur le fait que l'on se réfère à ceux de toute l'Afrique et non à ceux d'une région spécifique.

**Ajout tardif**

Et il y a une autre différence de sens, peut-être plus importante encore : l'expression *de l'Afrique* qualifie l'origine du clandestin, alors que *depuis l'Afrique* n'indique que **l'endroit par lequel il arrive en Europe**, qu'il soit en définitive africain, turc ou inuite (ce qui, convenons-en, est nettement plus rare).

Answer (score 0):

Il peut exister d'autres façons que la suivante de supprimer le manque de netteté de l'effet produit par  « depuis » ou « de » dans cette phrase, mais celle-ci est effective en même temps qu'elle ne demande pas tellement plus de mots;

- nous parlerons de la nouvelle mesure de l’UE pour combattre le passage de clandestins **venant d**'Afrique. (*aussi* **en provenance d**)

Les mots comme « de » ont de nombreuses fonctions dans le langage; donc lorsque l'on dégage du contexte que l'un de ces contextes ne se détache pas clairement il ne reste plus qu'une chose à faire: éviter le mot (« de » en l'occurrence) et trouver un autre moyen. Ceci est un principe de base dans l'approche à la question de savoir quand conserver un mot. Il est évidemment plus vite dit que fait de trouver le raisonnement utile dans chaque cas qui se présente.

Dans cet exemple « de » est « faible »  pour les raisons suivantes;
« de » peut endosser au moins quatre fonctions qui correspondent aux significations suivantes ;

- les futurs clandestins qui sont associés à l'Afrique en tant que personnes africaines qui s'expatrient, mais on ne sait pas vers quelle nation, peut être plusieurs
- les clandestins qui  sont **déjà** des clandestins en Afrique
- les futurs clandestins qui sont des Africains et qui vont se  diriger vers l'Europe
- combattre le passage des clandestins **à partir** de l'Afrique (*c'est à dire prendre des mesures en Afrique pour empêcher leur fuite hors d'Afrique*)

Bien sûr, le contexte dirige la compréhension et on déduira assez vite qu'il s'agit de la troisième possibilité; cependant ce n'est pas net, toutes ces possibilités qui s'insinuent sont des parasites pour la pensée et on préfère donc les éliminer (tout simplement en éliminant « de », mais évidemment il faut remplacer ce mot par un ou plusieurs autres).

Un raisonnement similaire s'applique à « depuis ».